# run program when usb connected to raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel, udev

I'm trying to run a program when I plug USB to my Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

I referenced below two
https://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device

1. write a *.rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d/ directory

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/81-usb.rules
```

2. fill with

```
KERNEL=="sda1", RUN+="echo Hello World > /home/pi/hello.txt"
```

3. restart udev

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

I almost tried every variation, rebooted a lot, just in case I'm missing something. But nothing works.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: udev is not bash.  You can't expect it to do bash redirects.  Put your code in a script and run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks stark.
Anyway I'm answering my own Question.

I changed it from

```
KERNEL=="sda1", RUN+="echo Hello World > /home/pi/hello.txt"
```

to

```
KERNEL=="sda1", RUN+="/home/pi/test.sh"
```

also did

```
chmod +x /home/pi/test.sh
```